# Scroll contexts are left open and they never get deleted or expired in Elasticsearch v7.3?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES v7.3 and using slicing to stream data from ES but what i observe is that after we stream the data a few times some scroll contexts are left open and they remain open for days and does not get expired or killed and hence the search keeps on going and high cpu spikes are observed. Also in the logs we get the following message

```
[2020-02-07T06:49:33,559][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchScrollAction] [ip-1-0-104-220] [1234717] Failed to execute query phase
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [ip-1-0-104-220][1.0.104.220:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query/scroll]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchContextMissingException: No search context found for id [1234717]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.getExecutor(SearchService.java:462) ~[elasticsearch-7.3.1.jar:7.3.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.runAsync(SearchService.java:344) ~[elasticsearch-7.3.1.jar:7.3.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:401) ~[elasticsearch-7.3.1.jar:7.3.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService.lambda$registerRequestHandler$10(SearchTransportService.java:367) ~[elasticsearch-7.3.1.jar:7.3.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:257) [x-pack-security-7.3.1.jar:7.3.1]
```

Would request if anyone can guide us if we are missing any setting on index level that we should enforce so that these open contexts get killed or get expired after a timeout is reached.

To check and delete the open contexts i am using the following command respectively,

```
GET _nodes/stats/indices?filter_path=**.open_contexts
DELETE /_search/scroll/_all
```

Moreover my timeouts are,

```
exports.ELASTICSEARCH = {
  PARALLEL_SLICES : 2,
  SCROLL_ALIVE_TIME : '5m',
  SLICE_ALIVE_TIME : '1m',
  SCROLL_SIZE : 10000,
  REQUEST_RETRY_COUNT : 5,
  REQUEST_TIMEOUT : 120000, // in milliSecond
  ERROR_RETRY_COUNT : 3

};
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the scroll alive time? 5 minutes is a lot of time and every time you make a request, that 5 minutes gets reset. If you are not doing a lot in between request, try setting that timeout to 30 seconds and see if that kills the scroll and free up some resources. There doesn't seem to be a way to manually close it though.

Comment: what happens if a timeout for a scroll is reached because in my case timeout is getting reached so i don't find the next scroll with its id and that request gets stuck?

Comment: I suggested 30 secs just so you could test and make sure the scroll IS getting deleted. Does your execution time vary a lot between each request? Basically, my suggestion is to fine tune your timeout a bit so resources are release fairly quickly. 5 minutes is quite a long time. Imagine you are trying to connect to a bad server but the connection waits 5 minutes before telling you it couldn't connect.

Comment: actually what is happening here is that scrolls are getting timeout but they are not sending the response back and hence my app is waiting for the response of that scroll and when i manually clean the scrolls then the app receives a response and the processing of that scroll gets completed.

Comment: Also i get your point that 5 min is a long time but my processing between two scroll requests takes time so i have to go with it.

Comment: Can you share your search code and configs? Also, try turning on logging at INFO level too. That should give you all the requests that are being made to ES. Make sure you are not running out of memory also

Comment: Can you also check to make sure that the context id returned from the scroll matches or differs from the one you have? It might be getting renewed and you might be ignoring that which could cause the above error message